# Bread from bread maker turns out strangely shaped

Tags: bread, equipment

I am a bread making newbie. I purchased a break maker and followed the instructions for white bread to start and pushed the button that outlined and got this:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: When you say “followed the instructions”: Did you measure your ingredients by weight or volume? Is your yeast fresh and active? And beyond these two points (aka “the usual suspects”), could you share the recipe and the instructions with us, please? How’s the taste? Can you describe the texture of crust and crumb? Can we perhaps get a photo that’s better focused, so that we can see the interior and the crust better? Just [edit] your post as needed. In the meantime, I would also recommend you take the [tour] and browse through the [help], especially [ask], to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: that looks like what happened when a relative forgot to put in the paddle for mixing...